# bootstrap modal disappears immediately

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a form on my website. When the submit button is activated I would like a bootstrap modal to appear and stay until you press the button on the modal to get back to the main menu. 
The modal appears for a second and then disappears. When I press the 'back' button on my browser window the modal then appears and stays until I press the 'ok' button on the modal. 
Any suggestions to a solution?

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap_cerulean.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
    body {padding-top:20px;}    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">           </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="well well-sm">
      <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
       <fieldset>
        <legend class="text-center">Udlevering af rute</legend>

        <!-- Bud input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Bruger">Avisbud</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <input id="Bruger" name="Bruger" type="text" placeholder="Skriv bud navn" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Avisrute nr.-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Rute nr">Rute nr.</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <input id="Rute nr" name="Rute nr" type="text" placeholder="Skriv rute nr." class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Form actions -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#udlevering_Modal">Udlevér rute</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div><script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</body>
</html>


<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="css/bootstrap_cerulean.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
    body {padding-top:20px;}    </style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">       </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="modal fade" id="udlevering_Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="well well-sm">
         <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Rute udleveret.</div><br />
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-large" href="manuel_opret.php" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span>  Til manuel menu &raquo;</a> 
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div><script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe this one could help you (seems to be solved) - [Bootstrap Modal immediately disappearing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648979/bootstrap-modal-immediately-disappearing?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Modal immediately disappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648979/bootstrap-modal-immediately-disappearing)

Comment: @RamizWachtler is correct. This code clearly double loads the Bootstrap JS (head, then body), which is addressed in the linked post.

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same issue couple of days back but dis trick worked for me, just change the button type to anchor tag as shown below.
e.g

```
<a type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Submit</a>
```

according to me the reason of the issue might be that it is trying to submit the form that's why the modal disappears immediately
Hope dis would help you..

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues. You have multiple HTML and body tags. You only need the modal div with your first HTML/Body tags.

Second you don't want the modal as a submit button on a form. Try type=button instead.