# Modal closes on open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to use a modal on my application and something weird is going on.  When I press the button to open the modal, it pops up and disappears right away.  I can see the modal content for a second before it closes.  Here is my code for the basic modal:

```
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Upload Images</button> <div class="spacer"></div>
  <textarea class="autosize-transition form-control" placeholder="Please enter information." id="form-field-11" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 200px; width: 720px"></textarea>

  <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            This is where you insert the content you want to display in the modal.
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <!-- footer area with buttons for a continued dialog -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

am I using a class that makes this happen? I have no idea why this behaves the way it does and I hope my question is clear enough for you pro's to dissect it and help me out.  Thanks to anyone in advance who knows why my modal closes right when I open it.

Comment: You need to add some info about the javascript which is managing the modal.

Comment: I am using the ACE template which includes bootstrap and a ton of minified js/jquery files I will try and find the JS that is supposed to be manipulating this modal.

Comment: @ZachyBear did you write any js which is conflicting with bootstraps js?

Comment: no, I just through in this basic modal

Comment: @ZachyBear `it pops up and disappears right away` suggests to me that some js is closing it. Try opening it manually

Comment: Seems similar to the question asked/answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648979/bootstrap-modal-immediately-disappearing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Modal immediately disappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648979/bootstrap-modal-immediately-disappearing)